# Create a list with increments up and down from a constant in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a constant value: 1.0

I'd like to create a single list consisting of four numbers above and four numbers below in consistent intervals, including the the constant in the center.  Let's say for example in 0.1 intervals. For  example

```
constantValue = 1.0
```

Do some pythonic magic...

```
outputList = [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
```

What's an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Hover over the arrow - _shows no research effort_

Comment: I mean, you could have edited the post to say something to the effect of "I know how to do a loop like _this_, but is there another way?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> constantValue = 1.0
>>> interval = 0.1
>>> delta = 4
>>> [constantValue + (i*interval) for i in range(-delta, delta+1)]
[0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy version

```
import numpy as np
constant_value = 1
STEP = 0.1
numbers = 4
np.arange(constant_value-numbers*STEP, numbers*STEP + constant_value+STEP, STEP)

array([0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

interval = 0.1
np.linspace(constantValue-interval*4,constantValue+interval*4,9)
```